# Неправильный подсчёт суммы всех покупок за месяц

Tags: mysql, sql

Почему неправильно подсчитало за второй месяц? Должно было получится 10500, а получилось 14000.

Остальные две строки, почему-то правильно посчитало. Почему так?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc8db/2

```
SELECT SUM(product.price), DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%Y') 
    FROM product 
        LEFT JOIN purchase ON purchase.product_id = product.id 
        LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = purchase.user_id 
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%Y')
```

---

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.3.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1
-- Время создания: Дек 27 2017 г., 13:49
-- Версия сервера: 5.6.24
-- Версия PHP: 5.6.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `lesson11`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `product`
--

INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `name`, `price`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 'ботинки', 3500, '2017-02-27 11:59:57'),
(2, 'мяч', 700, '2017-03-27 11:59:57'),
(3, 'Лыжи', 11000, '2017-12-27 12:00:22'),
(4, 'Велосипед', 7000, '2017-02-27 12:00:22'),
(5, 'сноуборд', 8000, '2017-12-27 12:01:18'),
(6, 'клюшка', 2400, '2017-12-27 12:01:18');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `purchase`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchase` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `purchase`
--

INSERT INTO `purchase` (`id`, `user_id`, `product_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 5),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 4, 2),
(4, 3, 1),
(5, 1, 4),
(6, 5, 3);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `user`
--

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Дима'),
(2, 'Андрей'),
(3, 'Вова'),
(4, 'Саша'),
(5, 'Лена');

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `product`
--
ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `purchase`
--
ALTER TABLE `purchase`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `product`
--
ALTER TABLE `product`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `purchase`
--
ALTER TABLE `purchase`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `user`
--
ALTER TABLE `user`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: в феврале были два раза куплены ботинки и один раз велосипед. Что не так? - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc8db/10

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, почему дата - свойство товара, а не покупки...

Comment: @Akina - это было первое, чего я понять сначала не мог :)))